# Disagreement on Using Type Aliases in Nested Classes

Tags: c++, templates, portability, type-alias

clang++ and g++ disagree about the validity of the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct thing {
    struct nested {
        typename thing::type num;
    };
    using type = int;
};
```

All versions of g++ (4.8 and up) compile this without issue, all versions of clang (3.0 and up) complain about `thing::type` not being defined.

Obviously if `thing` weren't a template, neither compiler would accept this, but who is correct here, and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Amazing. I guessed things would change if template `thing` is instanced. (I tried on wandbox.org against clang HEAD vs. gcc HEAD both with C++17. I added a member `T value;` which I could init and output.)  But still, gcc comiles and runs - clang doesn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, right? Very weird. Uncommon to find strong disagreement about the validity of simple code that has apparently stood across several major revisions of the compilers. I assume clang has to be "more" correct here, but I'm wondering if this is one of those situations where the standard dictates "no diagnostic required" so gcc isn't technically wrong.